# What are some ways to use aframe with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, aframe, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli. I've tried adding aframe directly in the index.html file, and also importing it in my top level main.js file. I just can't get Vue to recognize aframe elements.

Am I missing some boilerplate in the documentation?

Example warning:

> vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  -
> did you register the component correctly? For recursive components,
> make sure to provide the "name" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `aframe` to the `dependencies` in your `package.json`:

```
"browserify-css": "*", // required by aframe
"envify": "*",         // required by aframe
"aframe": "^1.2.0",    // aframe
```

add `aframe` to the compiled bundle:

```
var Vue = require('vue')
var App = require('./app.vue')
require('aframe')
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(App)
  }
})
```

and use the elements in your `<template>`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a-scene>
      <a-cylinder color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
    </a-scene>
  </div>
</template>
```

check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gftruj-aframe-vue?path=src%2Fapp.vue%3A11%3A0)

Answer (score 3):

- For development it is fine to import the CDN into your index.html
- For production it is recommended to require it into your Main.js

## Vue 2

To get rid of the warnings i recommend adding a array of components using Vue.config.ignoredElements placed in the main.js
Like so:

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'a-scene',
  'a-camera',
  'a-box'
  'a-image',
]
```

For a full list of components check out this Repo: [aframe-components-list](https://github.com/DeCartesius/aframe-components-list)

I recommend using the Vue.config.ignoredElements instead of registering your A-Frame components like normal Vue component, since they are not Vue components.

## Edit - Vue 3:

In Vue 3 Vue.config.ignoredElements in main.js will not work.

Instead, in your [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) file add the code below:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.module
        .rule('vue')
        .use('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          options.compilerOptions = {
            ...options.compilerOptions,
            isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('a-')
          }
          return options
        })
    }
  }
```

This should cover custom elements that start with 'a-'.

Comment: Vite version:
```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue({
    template: {
      compilerOptions: {
        isCustomElement: tag => tag.startsWith('a-'),
      }
    }
  })],
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for Vite (and Vue.js 3):

```
//vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith("a-"),
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```